# Recommended way to output plain text from a RESTful controller to PDF

Tags: spring, rest, pdf, spring-mvc

I'm looking for a way to automatically have my RESTful controller, which returns a String, output a pdf file to the calling browser, when the URI has a .pdf at the end:

http://localhost:9090/services-rs/notices/58357.pdf

Without the .pdf at the end, it currently merely returns the String, i.e. plain text, in the browser.

I tried adding:

```
<entry key="pdf" value="application/pdf"/>
```

to my mediatypes list in my ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, but evidently that didn't do the trick.

How do I go about this?  Is there a 3rd party library I need to use, or does Spring MVC have this ability built-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ContentNegotiatingViewResolver does not use the extension at the end of your URI.  It uses the Accept header in the request.  If you would like to use the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, ensure that your Accept header on the client side is using application/pdf.

If this is not possible for you, you will need to have a different controller.

Comment: Yes, but isn't there still a missing piece, here?  It would seem I require a class or library that knows how to automatically throw plain text into a pdf file, and I need to know what that is.

Comment: Your view resolver should map the string to something.  Presumably appending the .pdf extension to an object on the filesystem, or generating a pdf based on data that can be looked up by the string.

Comment: In my case, the String itself contains the entire plain text that I want dynamically converted to a PDF file.  I don't think I made that clear before, but it is crucial.  So, is there a way to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: You will need to use a 3rd party library.  If you want to plug it into Spring, you will need to make a custom HttpMessageConverter that will put the string in a pdf document.